# Npm script that finds and kills port that's in use

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm on a windows machine and every time I quit a node process, and try to restart again I get a `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8004`

I then have to do

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:8004
taskkill /F /PID <PID>
```

How can I write a script that finds and kills the PID by just doing `npm kill`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) the problem isn't about killing the server, it's about closing the port properly upon exiting. The program is obviously missing a `server.close()` in a `process.on('exit', ..)` and `process.on('uncaughtException', ..)`.

2) the first argument allowed next to npm is one of a predefined set. Read the output of `npm` about that.

3) to answer you question, and do the lazy work, you can put the two commands inside a batch file, set the listening port as a parameter and declare a script section in `package.json`,

```
{
  "name": "myserver",
  "scripts": {
    "kill": "killserver.bat"
  },
}
```

then use `npm run kill -- 8004`,
The port number being of course a parameter in the batch.
Note that this is longer and more complicated than simply calling the batch directly. see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script, it's useful to understand the possibilities offered by npm.